# ARM ASM Interrupt Vectors (.long in GNU ASM)

Tags: assembly, gnu, long-integer, bin

I am needing to jump to a very specific place in memory and in order to do this, I am needing to know how the GCC assembler puts .long into the final binary file.

```
.section ".flashconfig"
.long   0xFFFFFFFF
.long   0xFFFFFFFF
.long   0xFFFFFFFF
.long   0xFFFFFFFE
```

Which for my layout file, section `.flashconfig` **must** start at memory address `0x400`. When I assemble the assembly file I get:

```
:10040000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFFFFFD
```

In intel hex format starting at memory address `0x0400`, that is 12 bytes of `FF` and one byte `FE` then three more bytes of `FF`. This really makes it seem like it's reversed the bytes.

Is it the case that the program will jump to the address in the format inserted in the order entered in ASM `.long 0x12345678` or will it jump to the location assembled in the hex `0x87654321`? Currently my

My specific processor is the Cortex-M4, I am using unified syntax.

Comment: Looks like it was written in little endian format. Each `.long` was stored with Least significant byte first through to the Most significant byte.

Comment: @MichaelPetch that's what it looks like. I'm in the process of trying to get it in the asm, but because I have no debugging tools I can't really tell if it works or not.

Comment: If your cortex-M4 system is set up as a little endian system then the processor will see `.long 0x12345678` as `0x12345678`. Where you run into problems is if you generate code for one endian format and the processor is using something else.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I was running through the processor manual and this address is vector number 77, which is 71 away from my last configured vector. Do I need to configure all 71 other addresses or is there a way to offset it in gnu?

Comment: It may be offset by making a section, then placing that section below the location in the linker file. https://mcuoneclipse.com/2012/11/01/defining-variables-at-absolute-addresses-with-gcc/

Comment: its just little endian.  you dont need to run it nor a debugger you are looking at it correctly you can also take the elf version of the output and use arm-whatever-objdump -D to disassemble and you will see your vector table, etc.  yes you either need to pad with a bunch of other vectors, have some common infinite loop code you can use as a place to point them if you want.  or you need to do some work on the linker script, the former is easier to manage.